# Publish image in Facebook's news feed from web

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to post an image with some text in FB from my website. But as far as I've seen in the developer api, I could see either the image could be uploaded in an album (or FB creates an album for the app) or thumbnail image with link, but not a regular image in the user's wall.

Can somebody help me out here ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I've found a way to do it. This could be done as following:

1. Upload the image in the user's album. This could be achieved by 'photo' function in graph api with 'url' field set to the URL of the image or passing the image as post field.
2. Then create a feed with "link" field pointing to the image in the user's album -> the link would be something similar to

> `http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=<id_of_the_image_gotten_from_previous_operation>`

Now, you could see that a big image has been shared in news feed. To know about the photo function and feed function of graph api, check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle example for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try just making it a serialized link:

```
<a href="
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=12345567&link=http://yoursite.com?&picture=http://yoursite/assets/yourimage.jpg&name=This is my cool post&description=This is the content of the post&redirect_uri=http:/yoursite.html?"> </a>
```

But make sure to run it through a encoder to account for spaces:

Comment: No. This will simply share the thumbnail image with link in the news feed. I want the image to be big in size.